# org-agenda case-insensitive tag search?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

I use `C-c a m` to search for a tag, but the search is case-sensitive. By example if I enter `gnuplot`, only `section B` will be found

```
* section A     :Gnuplot:

* section B     :gnuplot:
```

**Question:** is it possible to do a case-insensitive tag search?

---

I know that:

- I can do a tag search `C-c a m` with "gnuplot|Gnuplot"
- I can do a "Search for keywords" using `C-c a s` which is case-insensitive, but this is a full text search (not only restricted to tags)

I would like to know if it is possible to do a "true" case-insensitive tag search (to catch "GnuPloT" too by example)

Comment: There might be a better way, but you can probably add a custom agenda search that does the same thing as `C-c a m` except that you `(let ((case-fold-search t)) ....)` around it.

Comment: @NickD thanks. However I fear I misunderstood your suggestion. Is it `(let ((case-fold-search t)) (org-tags-view nil "gnuPLot"))` ? This did not work in my case.

Comment: That's what I was suggesting: sorry it didn't work.

Comment: I think this is the line that would need to be changed, i.e., from `(while (let (case-fold-search)` to `(while (let (case-fold-search t)` as suggested (in part) by @NickD above:  https://code.orgmode.org/bzg/org-mode/src/master/lisp/org.el#L11331

Comment: It should be `(while (let ((case-fold-search t)) ...)` but even then I don't get the tags in a case insensitive way. Either I'm doing something wrong or there is more that needs to be done.